# Rotate a faceted, grouped bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, facet-grid

**UPDATED BELOW

I have created a plot, I literally need it horizontal, but the `coord_flip()` leaves the facets on the bottom instead of having nested groups on the left.

The data:

```
srvc_data <- structure(list(dept = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Distribution Centre Services", 
"IT", "Marketing", "Merchandise & Inventory", "Operations and Communication"
), class = "factor"), label = c("test5", "test7", "test3", "test10", 
"test4", "test6", "test2", "test1", "test11", "test12", "test9", 
"test8", "test18", "test19", "test15", "test17", "test13", "test16", 
"test20", "test14", "test22", "test21", "test25", "test23", "test24", 
"test27", "test26", "test28", "test29", "test31", "test33", "test30", 
"test32", "test38", "test36", "test37", "test43", "test34", "test35", 
"test40", "test39", "test42", "test41", "test5", "test7", "test3", 
"test10", "test4", "test6", "test2", "test1", "test11", "test12", 
"test9", "test8", "test18", "test19", "test15", "test17", "test13", 
"test16", "test20", "test14", "test22", "test21", "test25", "test23", 
"test24", "test27", "test26", "test28", "test29", "test31", "test33", 
"test30", "test32", "test38", "test36", "test37", "test43", "test34", 
"test35", "test40", "test39", "test42", "test41"), Gap = c(-0.07, 
-0.13, -0.15, -0.16, -0.16, -0.21, -0.22, -0.24, -0.24, -0.25, 
-0.3, -0.3, -0.18, -0.19, -0.24, -0.29, -0.3, -0.34, -0.36, -0.41, 
-0.46, -0.63, -0.16, -0.18, -0.21, -0.22, -0.27, -0.29, -0.31, 
-0.31, -0.35, -0.39, -0.42, -0.15, -0.15, -0.2, -0.21, -0.22, 
-0.27, -0.29, -0.29, -0.31, -0.36, -0.07, -0.13, -0.15, -0.16, 
-0.16, -0.21, -0.22, -0.24, -0.24, -0.25, -0.3, -0.3, -0.18, 
-0.19, -0.24, -0.29, -0.3, -0.34, -0.36, -0.41, -0.46, -0.63, 
-0.16, -0.18, -0.21, -0.22, -0.27, -0.29, -0.31, -0.31, -0.35, 
-0.39, -0.42, -0.15, -0.15, -0.2, -0.21, -0.22, -0.27, -0.29, 
-0.29, -0.31, -0.36), impeff = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("Importance", "Effectiveness"), class = "factor"), 
    score = c(0.87, 0.79, 0.78, 0.82, 0.81, 0.81, 0.92, 0.92, 
    0.78, 0.81, 0.86, 0.91, 0.79, 0.79, 0.87, 0.93, 0.9, 0.9, 
    0.82, 0.95, 0.91, 0.95, 0.77, 0.79, 0.82, 0.8, 0.83, 0.9, 
    0.91, 0.94, 0.89, 0.94, 0.91, 0.82, 0.74, 0.78, 0.81, 0.83, 
    0.85, 0.82, 0.81, 0.8, 0.83, 0.8, 0.66, 0.63, 0.66, 0.65, 
    0.6, 0.7, 0.68, 0.54, 0.56, 0.56, 0.61, 0.61, 0.6, 0.63, 
    0.64, 0.6, 0.56, 0.46, 0.54, 0.45, 0.32, 0.61, 0.61, 0.61, 
    0.58, 0.56, 0.61, 0.6, 0.63, 0.54, 0.55, 0.49, 0.67, 0.59, 
    0.58, 0.6, 0.61, 0.58, 0.53, 0.52, 0.49, 0.47)), row.names = c(NA, 
-86L), .Names = c("dept", "label", "Gap", "impeff", "score"), class = "data.frame")
```

And the code:

```
ggplot(data = srvc_data, aes(x = label, y = score)) + 
  geom_bar( aes(fill = impeff),stat = "identity", position = "dodge",width = 1) +
  facet_grid(~dept, switch = "x", scales = "free", space = "free") +

  #coord_flip()+
```

The plot (without the flip) looks like the below, I need it horizontal, with the facet categories on the far left. How does the `coord_flip()` work? Why wouldn't it also flip/move the facet strips? Please ignore the crammed formatting!

[image]

**UPDATE
So thanks to @neilfws I have fixed the plot, by switching the order of the data.

```
ggplot(data = srvc_data, aes(x = label, y = score)) + 
  geom_bar( aes(fill = impeff),stat = "identity", position = "dodge",width = 1) +
  facet_grid(dept~., switch = "y", scales = "free_y", space = "free") +
  coord_flip()
```

Now I have the correctly oriented plot, but there is lots of unused space for all the labels that are unused in each facet. Within the `facet_grid` call, setting `scales = "free"` doesn't work, nor does `drop = T`. Any ideas? Plot below for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `coord_flip`, you also need to reverse the faceting relationship (~), to place it on the side, and the `switch`, to place it on the y-axis. Does this get you close to what you want?

```
ggplot(srvc_data, aes(label, score)) + 
  geom_bar( aes(fill = impeff), stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 1) +
  facet_grid(dept ~ ., switch = "y", scales = "free", space = "free") + coord_flip()
```

Comment: Ah hah, I get it now. Thanks for that! While I have you, any way to ignore the unused labels in each facet? I thought I would specify "free.y" but I am getting an error if I use anything other that "free".

edit: how do the scales and space calls work in facet?

Comment: I think `free` has the same effect as `free_y` (with underscore not `.`) in this case.

Comment: See previous comment. Both `free` and `free_y` work for me. I don't know why you are seeing the unused labels. I have `ggplot2` 2.2.1.

Comment: I was on 2.1.0, updated and it now works as described. Many thanks!